# Shade Graphviz object with patterns

Tags: graphviz

I didn't see any documentation for shading patterns, only solid fill color for Graphviz. Does anybody know how to do it, or is it not possible?

Like the pattern fill here. https://www.ablebits.com/office-addins-blog/2012/03/28/excel-charts-tips/

Comment: Can you be a bit more precise in what you would like to have. Did you search for "graphviz shading"  or "graphviz shade"?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The closest thing to what you want is probably gradients.

In Graphviz's **Node, Edge and Graph Attributes** page, it supports gradients when specifying [color lists](https://www.graphviz.org/doc/info/attrs.html#k:colorList).

[image]

You can use them referring to these [examples](https://graphviz.readthedocs.io/en/stable/examples.html).

Another alternative which would be a bigger hassle is use the [shapefile](https://www.graphviz.org/doc/info/attrs.html#d:shapefile) attribute and build a shapefile per pattern although this feature is deprecated.

A third option would be if you are outputting in SVG format, is to do some post processing on the generated SVG to apply texture patterns on the nodes.

Comment: this is good enough. I just need some pattern... how ever ugly.